# Do something every x (milli)seconds in pygame

Tags: python, function, pygame, milliseconds, seconds

I'm learing Python and Pygame, and my first thing I'm making is a simple Snake game. I'm trying to make it so that the snake moves once every 0.25 seconds. Here is the part of my code that loops:

```
while True:
    check_for_quit()

    clear_screen()

    draw_snake()
    draw_food()

    check_for_direction_change()

    move_snake() #How do I make it so that this loop runs at normal speed, but move_snake() only executes once every 0.25 seconds?

    pygame.display.update()
```

I want all of the other function to run normally, but move_snake() to only occur once every 0.25 seconds. I've looked it up and found a few answers but they all seem too complicated for someone who's making their first ever Python script.

Would it be possible to actually get an example of what my code should look like rather than just telling me which function I need to use? Thanks!

Comment: dont use sleep it will stop the whole game instead of just the snake

Answer (score 17):

There are several approaches, like keeping track of the system time or using a `Clock` and counting ticks.

But the simplest way is to use the event queue and creating an event every x ms, using [`pygame.time.set_timer()`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.set_timer):

> **pygame.time.set_timer()**

*repeatedly create an event on the event queue*

> 

`set_timer(eventid, milliseconds) -> None`

> Set an event type to appear on the event queue every given number of milliseconds. The first event will not appear until the amount of time has passed.
>
> Every event type can have a separate timer attached to it. It is best to use the value between pygame.USEREVENT and pygame.NUMEVENTS.
>
> To disable the timer for an event, set the milliseconds argument to 0.

Here's a small, running example where the snake moves every 250 ms:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((300, 300))
player, dir, size = pygame.Rect(100,100,20,20), (0, 0), 20
MOVEEVENT, t, trail = pygame.USEREVENT+1, 250, []
pygame.time.set_timer(MOVEEVENT, t)
while True:
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_w]: dir = 0, -1
    if keys[pygame.K_a]: dir = -1, 0
    if keys[pygame.K_s]: dir = 0, 1
    if keys[pygame.K_d]: dir = 1, 0
    
    if pygame.event.get(pygame.QUIT): break
    for e in pygame.event.get():
        if e.type == MOVEEVENT: # is called every 't' milliseconds
            trail.append(player.inflate((-10, -10)))
            trail = trail[-5:]
            player.move_ip(*[v*size for v in dir])
            
    screen.fill((0,120,0))
    for t in trail:
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255,0,0), t)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255,0,0), player)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

[image]

---

Since pygame 2.0.1, it's quite easy to schedule things since `pygame.time.set_timer` now allows custom events to be fired once.

Here's a simple example of a way to run a function X seconds in the future once:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((640, 480))
ACTION = pygame.event.custom_type() # our custom event that contains an action
clock = pygame.time.Clock()


def main():
    shield = 0

    # function to activate the shield
    # note that shield is NOT just a boolean flag,
    # but an integer. Everytime we activate the shield,
    # we increment it by 1. If we want to deactivate the 
    # shield later, we can test if the deactivate event
    # is the latest one. If not, then nothing should happen.
    def activate_shield():
        nonlocal shield
        shield += 1
        return shield

    # function that creates the function that is triggered
    # after some time. It's nested so we can pass and capture
    # the id variable to check if the event is actually the
    # last deactivate event. If so, we reset shield to 0.
    def remove_shield(id):
        def action():
            nonlocal shield
            if shield == id:
                shield = 0
        return action

    while True:
        for e in pygame.event.get():
            if e.type == pygame.QUIT: return
            
            if e.type == pygame.KEYDOWN: 
                # activate the shield
                id = activate_shield()
                # deactivate it 2000ms in the future
                # pygame will post this event into the event queue at the right time
                pygame.time.set_timer(pygame.event.Event(ACTION, action=remove_shield(id)), 2000, 1)
                
            if e.type == ACTION:
                # if there's an ACTION event, invoke its action!!!
                e.action()
                
        screen.fill('black')
          
        # is the shield active?
        if shield:
            pygame.draw.circle(screen, 'red', (320, 220), 35, 4)
            
        # our green little guy
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, 'green', (300, 200, 40, 40))
        pygame.display.flip()
        clock.tick(60)

main()
```

Minimal example: <kbd>[[image] repl.it@queueseven/Simple-Scheduler](https://repl.it/@queueseven/Simple-Scheduler#main.py)</kbd>

Comment: Good example program!

Comment: Is there a way to have the program read a new command from a command_list every 1250 ms?
Move_North ... Move_East ... Move_South ?

Comment: @user1839239 Sure. You could create some constants like `MOVE_EAST = (1, 0)` etc, then create the list of commands like `command_list  = [MOVE_EAST, MOVE_NORTH, ....]` and in the event handler do something like `dir = command_list.pop(0)` to get the next command before the `player.move_ip...` line.

Comment: Sounds good! Could you write a small example program that would illustrate your idea? I'm a noob!

Answer (score 7):

Use the [Clock module of Pygame](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock) to keep track of time. Specifically the method `tick` of the `Clock` class will report to you the number of milliseconds since the last time you called `tick`. Therefore you can call `tick` once at the beginning (or at the end) of every iteration in your game loop and store its return value in a variable called `dt`. Then use `dt` to update your time-dependent game state variables.

```
time_elapsed_since_last_action = 0
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

while True: # game loop
    # the following method returns the time since its last call in milliseconds
    # it is good practice to store it in a variable called 'dt'
    dt = clock.tick() 

    time_elapsed_since_last_action += dt
    # dt is measured in milliseconds, therefore 250 ms = 0.25 seconds
    if time_elapsed_since_last_action > 250:
        snake.action() # move the snake here
        time_elapsed_since_last_action = 0 # reset it to 0 so you can count again
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to control something over time in Pygame you have two options:

1. Use [`pygame.time.get_ticks()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.get_ticks) to measure time and and implement logic that controls the object depending on the time.
2. Use the timer event. Use [`pygame.time.set_timer()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.set_timer) to repeatedly create a [`USEREVENT`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html) in the event queue. Change object states when the event occurs.

The examples in the answers to the following questions show how to use this:

- [Spawning multiple instances of the same object concurrently in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62112754/spawning-multiple-instances-of-the-same-object-concurrently-in-python/62112894#62112894)
  <kbd>[PYGBAG demo](https://rabbid76.github.io/PyGameExamplesAndAnswers/examples/minimal_exmaples_web/pygame_minimal_timer_spawn_objects/build/web/)</kbd>
  [image]
- [Is there a way to have different tick rates for differents parts of my code in pygame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71088920/is-there-a-way-to-have-different-tick-rates-for-differents-parts-of-my-code-in-p/71089817#71089817)
- [How can I show explosion image when collision happens?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64305426/how-can-i-show-explosion-image-when-collision-happens/64305746#64305746)
  <kbd>[PYGBAG demo](https://rabbid76.github.io/PyGameExamplesAndAnswers/examples/minimal_exmaples_web/pygame_minimal_timer_for_a_period_of_time/build/web/)</kbd>
  [image]
- [How to create a visual timer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71134979/how-to-create-a-visual-timer/71165600#71165600)
  [image]

---

Minimal example for option 1: <kbd>[PYGBAG demo](https://rabbid76.github.io/PyGameExamplesAndAnswers/examples/minimal_exmaples_web/pygame_minimal_timer_get_ticks_1/build/web/)</kbd>

```py
import pygame

pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 200))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
rect = pygame.Rect(0, 80, 20, 20)

time_interval = 500 # 500 milliseconds == 0.5 seconds
next_step_time = 0

run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False 

    current_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
    if current_time > next_step_time:
        next_step_time += time_interval
        rect.x = (rect.x + 20) % window.get_width()

    window.fill(0)
    pygame.draw.rect(window, (255, 0, 0), rect)
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(100)

pygame.quit()
exit()
```

Minimal example for option 2: <kbd>[PYGBAG demo](https://rabbid76.github.io/PyGameExamplesAndAnswers/examples/minimal_exmaples_web/pygame_minimal_timer_event_1/build/web/)</kbd>

```py
import pygame

pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((400, 200))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
rect = pygame.Rect(0, 80, 20, 20)

time_interval = 500 # 500 milliseconds == 0.5 seconds
timer_event = pygame.USEREVENT+1
pygame.time.set_timer(timer_event, time_interval) 

run = True
while run:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False 

        if event.type == timer_event:
            rect.x = (rect.x + 20) % window.get_width()

    window.fill(0)
    pygame.draw.rect(window, (255, 0, 0), rect)
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(100)

pygame.quit()
exit()
```

[image]