# Recall a function every x milliseconds on Tkinter (Pygame's set_timer equivalent)

Tags: python, tkinter

I am developping a little application for plotting a network graph, showing "*how fast your ping is*". [Here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/134033/network-graph-using-tkinter-optimize-canvas-display) is the related code review post.

Basically, I have a thread managing a canvas. This thread targets to the following method (simplified):

```
def update(self):
    # Basically draw a vertical line on the right of the canvas
    self.draw_line(tag="spike")

    # Move all lines by -1 px and delete the lines outside the canvas
    # This can be somewhat long.
    lines = list(self.canvas.find_withtag("spike"))
    while len(lines) > self.WIDTH:
        self.canvas.delete(lines.pop(0))
    for l in lines:
        x0, y0, x1, y1 = self.canvas.coords(l)
        self.canvas.coords(l, x0 - 1, y0, x1 - 1, y1)

    # Recall in 10ms
    if self.alive:
        self.root.after(10, self.update)
```

So as you might think, this function is a bit slow on large canvas (for example 800x600). Because it uses a recall method **after** its computation, I have a recall time of `computation_time + 10`ms. I would like to have a recall time of **exactly 10ms**.

As I saw on [a SO post about PyGame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18948981/do-something-every-x-milliseconds-in-pygame) the method `pygame.time.set_timer()` does this kind of thing on PyGame. I would like to know if there is an equivalent for `Tkinter`.

Rergards,