# How can I show explosion image when collision happens?

Tags: python, pygame

I don't know why explosion effect doesn't happen.
The other images were drawn well, but only explosion image didn't

```py
explosion = pygame.image.load(os.path.join(image_path, "explosion.png"))
explosion_size = explosion.get_rect().size
explosion_width = explosion_size[0]
```

```py
for missile_idx, missile_val in enumerate(missiles):
    missile_pos_x = missile_val[0]
    missile_pos_y = missile_val[1]

    #weapon information upgrade
    missile_rect = missile.get_rect()
    missile_rect.left = missile_pos_x
    missile_rect.top = missile_pos_y

    if missile_rect.colliderect(rock_rect):
        explosion_sound.play()
        **explosion_pos_x = missile_pos_x
        explosion_pos_y = missile_pos_y
        screen.blit(explosion,(explosion_pos_x,explosion_pos_y))**
        del(rock)
        del(missiles)
        missiles = []

        # missile position coordination
        missiles = [[m[0], m[1] - missile_speed] for m in missiles]

        # top missile elimination
        missiles = [[m[0], m[1]] for m in missiles if m[1]>0]
```

Comment: How long do you want to show the explosion image?

Comment: I want to show it only when collision happens for about 2 seconds.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry I didn't check yet, as soon as I finish I'll comment. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: This issue is solved, thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The explosion is just shown for a short moment. Use [`pygame.time.get_ticks()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.get_ticks) to return the number of milliseconds since `pygame.init()` was called. Calculate the point in time after that the explosion image has to be removed. Add the coordinates of the explosion and the end time point to the head of a list (`explosionList` ). Draw the explosion(s) in the main application loop. Remove the expired explosions from the tail of the list:

```py
explosionList = []

while run:
    current_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
    # [...]

    for missile_idx, missile_val in enumerate(missiles)
        # [...]

        if missile_rect.colliderect(rock_rect):
            explosion_sound.play()

            explosion_pos_x = missile_pos_x
            explosion_pos_y = missile_pos_y
            end_time = current_time + 2000 # 2000 milliseconds = 2 seconds
            explosionList.insert(0, (end_time, explosion_pos_x, explosion_pos_y))

            # [...]

    for i in range(len(explosionList)):
        if current_time < explosionList[i][0]:
            screen.blit(explosion, (explosionList[i][1], explosionList[i][2]))
        else:
            explosionList = explosionList[:i]
            break
    
    # [...]
```

With this algorithm it is possible to manage multiple explosions.

See [Time, timer event and clock](https://github.com/Rabbid76/PyGameExamplesAndAnswers/blob/master/documentation/pygame/pygame_time_and_timer_event.md#time-timer-event-and-clock)

---

Minimal example <kbd>[PYGBAG demo](https://rabbid76.github.io/PyGameExamplesAndAnswers/examples/minimal_exmaples_web/pygame_minimal_timer_for_a_period_of_time/build/web/)</kbd>

[image]

```py
import pygame
pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((210, 210))

def create_rectangles():
    global rectangles
    w, h = window.get_size()
    rectangles = []
    for x in range(0, w - 60, 60):
        for y in range(0, h - 60, 60):
            rectangles.append(pygame.Rect(x + 30, y + 30, 30, 30))

create_rectangles()
hit_list = []
fade_out_time = 3000

run = True
while run:
    current_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
    
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    point = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    collideindex = pygame.Rect(point, (1, 1)).collidelist(rectangles)
    if collideindex >= 0:
        end_time = current_time + fade_out_time
        hit_list.insert(0, (end_time, rectangles[collideindex].center))
        del rectangles[collideindex]
    if not hit_list and not rectangles:
        create_rectangles()

    window.fill(0)
    for r in rectangles:
        pygame.draw.rect(window, (255, 0, 0), r)
    for i in range(len(hit_list)):
        delta_time = hit_list[i][0] - current_time
        if delta_time > 0:
            radius = round(30 * delta_time / fade_out_time)
            pygame.draw.circle(window, (255, 255, 0), hit_list[i][1], radius)
        else:
            hit_list = hit_list[:i]
            break
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show explosion image for a while this method can be useful.

```
explosion_list = [] # list for explosion effect
running = True
while running:
     start_time = pygame.time.get_ticks() # add time for explosion effect

     for missile_idx, missile_val in enumerate(missiles):
         missile_pos_x = missile_val[0]
         missile_pos_y = missile_val[1]

         #weapon information upgrade
         missile_rect = missile.get_rect()
         missile_rect.left = missile_pos_x
         missile_rect.top = missile_pos_y

         if missile_rect.colliderect(rock_rect):
             explosion_sound.play()
             explosion_pos_x = missile_pos_x
             explosion_pos_y = missile_pos_y
             explosion_time = start_time + 2000 # 1000 milliseconds = 2 seconds
             **explosion_list.insert(0, (explosion_time, explosion_pos_x, explosion_pos_y))**
             del(rock)
             del(missiles)
             missiles = []
            
             # missile position coordination
             missiles = [[m[0], m[1] - missile_speed] for m in missiles]

             # top missile elimination
             missiles = [[m[0], m[1]] for m in missiles if m[1]>0]
                        
             **for i in range(len(explosion_list)):
                 if start_time < explosion_time:
                    pygame.display.update()
                    screen.blit(explosion, (explosion_pos_x - 30, explosion_pos_y - 30))
                    pygame.time.delay(10)**
                    else:
                         explosion_list = explosion_list[:i]
```