# How to make hitmarker effect like in the shooter games? - Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I wanna make a hitmarker efffect like in the shooter games with pygame.

When you click on the "resized_egg" hitmarker is gonna appear for about 0.2 seconds. Like this:

[image: I wanna make a hitmarker effect like this]

I tried it with `screen.blit()` but i didn't manage it to make it.

```
# [...]
egg = pygame.image.load("egg.png")
resized_egg = pygame.transform.scale(egg, (282, 352))
pygame.image.load("hitmarker.png")
# [...]

while Loop: # main game loop
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            Loop = False


        if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            if event.button == 1: # 1 == left click
                egg_rect = resized_egg.get_rect(topleft = (260,150))
                if egg_rect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                    # [...]
#[...]
```

Comment: It would be easier to tell if you provided an MWE. However, here's the idea: you blit the background, then the sprites (eg the egg), and then visual effects (ie the marker), then you flip. If you don't blit in the correct order, the marker won't be visible.

Comment: as you said in your question. When you click it then create new object and add to list of displayed object. And if this object will have variable which you set `time_to_remove = current_time + 0.2 seconds` then in every loop you can compare it with current time and remove it from list when `current_time >= time_to_remove`

Comment: MWE(Minimal Working Example) is the same as MRE([mre]) which You should read about

Comment: Related [How can I show explosion image when collision happens?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64305426/how-can-i-show-explosion-image-when-collision-happens/64305746#64305746) and [Adding a particle effect to my clicker game](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64793618/adding-a-particle-effect-to-my-clicker-game/64794954#64794954).

Answer (score 0):

You should use list (or `pygame.sprite.Group`) to keep hitboxes with `current_time + 200 ms`

And in every loop you should check every hitbox on list if it is time to remove it from list.

And later you should draw all hitboxes from list.

---

**Working example:**

At start I create empty list

```
all_items = []
```

In loop I get

```
current_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
```

When I click mouse button then I add items to this list with `remove_at`

```
        x, y = event.pos

        item = {
            'rect': pygame.Rect(x-10, y-10, 20, 20),
            'remove_at': current_time + 500,  # 500ms = 0.5s
        }

        all_items.append(item)
```

Later I use `for`-loop to keep only items which have `remove_at > current_time`

```
    keep_items = []
    
    for item in all_items:
        if item['remove_at'] > current_time:
            keep_items.append(item)
        else:
            print('removed:', item)
            
    all_items = keep_items
```

And later I draw all items from this list:

```
    for item in all_items:    
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, RED, item['rect'])
```

---

Full code:

```
import pygame

# --- constants --- (UPPER_CASE_NAMES)

SCREEN_WIDTH = 800
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 600

FPS = 25 # for more than 220 it has no time to update screen

BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
RED   = (255, 0, 0)

# --- functions --- (lower_case_names)

# --- main ---

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode( (SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT) )

all_items = []

# --- mainloop ---

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

running = True
while running:

    current_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
    
    # --- events ---

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                running = False
    
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            x, y = event.pos
            item = {
                'rect': pygame.Rect(x-10, y-10, 20, 20),
                'remove_at': current_time + 500,  # 500ms = 0.5s
            }
            all_items.append(item)
            print("add at:", x, y)
            
    # --- changes/moves/updates ---

    # filter objects
    
    keep_items = []
    
    for item in all_items:
        if item['remove_at'] > current_time:
            keep_items.append(item)
        else:
            print('removed:', item)
            
    all_items = keep_items
    
    # --- draws ---

    screen.fill(BLACK)

    for item in all_items:    
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, RED, item['rect'])
    
    pygame.display.flip()

    # --- FPS ---

    ms = clock.tick(FPS)
    #pygame.display.set_caption('{}ms'.format(ms)) # 40ms for 25FPS, 16ms for 60FPS
    fps = clock.get_fps()
    pygame.display.set_caption('FPS: {}'.format(fps))
    
# --- end ---

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: x, y = event.pos
AttributeError: 'Event' object has no attribute 'pos'

Comment: what PyGame version do you use? Check `print(pygame.__version__)`. I tested it on `pygame 2.0.1 (SDL 2.0.14, Python 3.8.5)` Did you use it for `MOUSEBUTTONDOWN` or `MOUSEBUTTONUP`?  Other events may not have `pos` which is mouse position.

Comment: do you get this error with my code or with your code?

Comment: my pygame version is 1.9.6 also i wanna make it to appear on where you click, i tried pygame.mouse.get.position() but the hitmarker appears at the bottom right of the mouse. This is my source code: https://www.paste.tc/raw/test-54083

Comment: i get the error after adding your code on my code

Comment: how did you add it ? `event.pos` has to be in `if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:`. Besides in your code I see `if egg_rect.collidepoint(event.pos):` inside `if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:` so it should work. It has to be used in corrrect event. Key events don't have `pos`. Maybe simply use `print(event.type)` before `x, y = event.pos` to see for what event you use it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232669/discussion-between-zgn-and-furas).