# Rendering Images At a Different Framerate Than The Game Window

Tags: python, pygame, frame-rate

I have an animation I need to play every time the mouse button is clicked.

I have the frames stored in a list, for every frame that Pygame renders, one frame in the list is `blit` to the screen.

My issue is that because this happens every frame, the animation is played at 1000fps, even though there are only 8 frames, so the animation is unnoticeable. Is there any way to run the animation at 16fps while still allowing Pygame to run through the game loop at normal speeds? I have a game that needs to be run at Pygame's normal render speed but the animations should be played slower.

Here is an example of what I am currently doing:

```
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))


running = True
while running:
    screen.fill('#000000')
    mouse_pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

    explosion = (pygame.image.load('assets/Explosion/E_1.png'), pygame.image.load('assets/Explosion/E_2.png'),
                 pygame.image.load('assets/Explosion/E_3.png'), pygame.image.load('assets/Explosion/E_4.png'),
                 pygame.image.load('assets/Explosion/E_5.png'), pygame.image.load('assets/Explosion/E_6.png'),
                 pygame.image.load('assets/Explosion/E_7.png'), pygame.image.load('assets/Explosion/E_8.png'))

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
            exit()
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            for frame in explosion:
                framerect = frame.get_rect(center=mouse_pos)
                screen.blit(frame, framerect)
        
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, the animation is rendered in 1 frame because you render the animations in a for loop inside the application loop. You need to use the application loop. Limit the number of frames with  [`pygame.time.Clock.tick`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock.tick) and load the frames once before the application loop to improve performance.

In the following example,  `clock.tick(100)` sets the frames per second, and `animate_frames = 10` defines how many frames of animation will be displayed:

```py
import pygame

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))

try:
    explosion = (pygame.image.load('assets/Explosion/E_1.png'), pygame.image.load('assets/Explosion/E_2.png'),
                pygame.image.load('assets/Explosion/E_3.png'), pygame.image.load('assets/Explosion/E_4.png'),
                pygame.image.load('assets/Explosion/E_5.png'), pygame.image.load('assets/Explosion/E_6.png'),
                pygame.image.load('assets/Explosion/E_7.png'), pygame.image.load('assets/Explosion/E_8.png'))
except:
    explosion = []
    for i in range(10):
        e = pygame.Surface((100, 100), pygame.SRCALPHA)
        pygame.draw.circle(e, (200 - i * 10, 200 - i * 20, 0), (50, 50), i*5)
        explosion.append(e) 

clock = pygame.time.Clock() 
animate_frames = 10
animations = []
running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
            exit()
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            animations.append([event.pos, 0])

    screen.fill('#000000')
    for animation in animations[:]:
        animation[1] += 1
        frame_index = animation[1] // animate_frames
        if frame_index < len(explosion):
            frame = explosion[frame_index]
            framerect = frame.get_rect(center=animation[0])
            screen.blit(frame, framerect)
        else:
            animations.remove(animation)
        
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(100)

pygame.quit()
```

<kbd>[PYGBAG demo](https://rabbid76.github.io/PyGameExamplesAndAnswers/examples/minimal_exmaples_web/pygame_minimal_timer_animation_2/build/web/)</kbd>

[image]

---

Also see [How can I show explosion image when collision happens?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64305426/how-can-i-show-explosion-image-when-collision-happens/64305746#64305746)