# How to slow down the speed of these moving shapes in python?

Tags: python, pygame

I am making space invaders in my own version. Instead of bullets, I use lasers that are randomly shot from an enemy spaceship. However, the lasers move too fast and if I use `time.sleep(1)`, the whole program will freeze every second. Here is my code and help me find out what I can do to fix it.

```
# importing packages
import pygame
import random
import time

# Setting a display caption
pygame.display.set_caption("Space Invaders")

spaceship = pygame.image.load("spaceship2.png")
blue_enemy = pygame.image.load("blue_enemy.png")
green_enemy = pygame.image.load("green_enemy.png")
orange_enemy = pygame.image.load("orange_enemy.png")
pink_enemy = pygame.image.load("pink_enemy.png")
yellow_enemy = pygame.image.load("yellow_enemy.png")

# Setting a display width and height and then creating it
display_width = 700
display_height = 500
display_size = [display_width, display_height]
game_display = pygame.display.set_mode(display_size)

def message(sentence, color, x, y, font_type, display):
    sentence = font_type.render(str.encode(sentence), True, color)
    display.blit(sentence, [x, y])


def main():
    # Spaceship coordinates
    spaceship_x = 300
    spaceship_y = 375
    spaceship_x_change = 0
    blue_enemy_health = 5
    green_enemy_health = 5
    orange_enemy_health = 5
    pink_enemy_health = 5
    yellow_enemy_health = 5

    # Initializing pygame
    pygame.init()

    # Creating colors
    black = (0, 0, 0)
    red = (0, 0, 0)
    white = (255, 255, 255)

    seconds_counter = pygame.time.get_ticks()

    done = False

    # Creating a loop to keep program running
    while not done:

        # --- Event Processing and controls
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                done = True
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    spaceship_x_change = 7
                elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    spaceship_x_change = -7
                elif event.key == pygame.K_r:
                    red = (255, 0, 0)
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                spaceship_x_change = 0
                red = (0, 0, 0)

        spaceship_x += spaceship_x_change

        # Timer
        seconds = (pygame.time.get_ticks() - seconds_counter) / 1000

        # Preventing the ship from going off the screen
        if spaceship_x > display_width - 140:
            spaceship_x -= 10
        if spaceship_x < 1:
            spaceship_x += 10

        # Setting Display color
        game_display.fill(black)

        laser_coords = [70, 209, 348, 505, 630]
        # this is where i make the random lasers
        # Creating a spaceship, lasers, and enemies
        pygame.draw.rect(game_display, red, [spaceship_x + 69, 70, 4, 310])
        pygame.draw.rect(game_display, white, [random.choice(laser_coords), 85, 4, 200])
        game_display.blit(spaceship, (spaceship_x, spaceship_y))
        message(str(blue_enemy_health), white, 65, 10, font, game_display)
        game_display.blit(blue_enemy, (20, 25))
        message(str(green_enemy_health), white, 203, 10, font, game_display)
        game_display.blit(green_enemy, (160, 25))
        message(str(orange_enemy_health), white, 341, 10, font, game_display)
        game_display.blit(orange_enemy, (300, 25))
        message(str(pink_enemy_health), white, 496, 10, font, game_display)
        game_display.blit(pink_enemy, (440, 25))
        message(str(yellow_enemy_health), white, 623, 10, font, game_display)
        game_display.blit(yellow_enemy, (580, 25))

        # Updating Screen so changes take places
        pygame.display.update()

        # Setting FPS
        FPS = pygame.time.Clock()
        FPS.tick(60)
```

Also a sidenote, I haven't included all my code.

Comment: Hey, I believe this well help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18948981/do-something-every-x-milliseconds-in-pygame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In pygame the system time can be obtained by calling [`pygame.time.get_ticks()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.get_ticks), which returns the number of milliseconds since [`pygame.init()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/pygame.html#pygame.init) was called. See [`pygame.time`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html) module.

Calculate the point in time when the position of the laser needs to be changed. Get a new random position the current time is greater than the calculated time. Calculate the new random point in time when the position needs to be changed again:

```py
def main():
    # [...]

    change_laser_coord_time = 0
    laser_coords = [70, 209, 348, 505, 630]
    laser_coord_x = random.choice(laser_coords)

    # Creating a loop to keep program running
    while not done:
        # [...]

        current_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
        if current_time > change_laser_coord_time:
            change_laser_coord_time = current_time + 1000
            laser_coord_x = random.choice(laser_coords)

        # [...]

        pygame.draw.rect(game_display, white, [laser_coord_x, 85, 4, 200])
```