# Sprite (Surface) delay Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I am learning pygame. I have two sprites (Surface) on the screen. I want the first sprite to start moving a little later than the second sprite. That is, I want to delay one sprite without delaying the entire game. How can i do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do something every x (milli)seconds in pygame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18948981/do-something-every-x-milliseconds-in-pygame)

Comment: @Cortex0101 The question is not about doing something every x seconds, but after a few seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`pygame.time.get_ticks()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.get_ticks) to get the number of milliseconds since [`pygame.init()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/pygame.html#pygame.init):

```py
while True:

    # move sprite 1
    # [...]

    elapsed_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
    if elapsed_time > 3000: # 3000 millisecods = 3 seconds
        # more than 3 seconds have elapsed 

        # move sprite 2
        # [...]
```